# Running traekif on swarm mode with a multiple ports backend

Tags: docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, traefik

I’m having some issues using Traefik in a Swarm. With the following configuration I’m expecting traffic on port 80 to reach the **traefik** service and then be dispatched it a dedicated port on the **proxy** service but it seems the traffic does not go through.

traefik:
    image: traefik:1.3.5
    command: --web --docker --docker.swarmmode --docker.watch --docker.domain=app.dev --logLevel=DEBUG
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /dev/null:/traefik.toml
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure

proxy:
    image: 'myapp/proxy'
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        - "traefik.backend=proxy"
        - "traefik.web.frontend.rule=Host:www.app.dev"
        - "traefik.web.port=8000"
        - "traefik.wss.frontend.rule=Host:wss.app.dev"
        - "traefik.wss.protocol=ws"
        - "traefik.wss.port=9002"
        - "traefik.api.frontend.rule=Host:api.app.dev"
        - "traefik.api.port=8002"
        - "traefik.lnr.frontend.rule=Host:lnr.app.dev"
        - "traefik.lnr.port=9001"
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure

I have the following entry in the logs:

`app_traefik.1.84giy7wqf3n6@moby    | time="2017-08-08T11:27:34Z" level=debug msg="Filtering container without port and no traefik.port label app_proxy.1"`

I get a 404 when I send a request to the app:

`curl -H "Host:www.app.dev" http://localhost
404 page not found`

Is the multi ports for a single backend taken into account in the context of a Swarm as it is when run with Docker Compose ?

Any idea what I’m missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out it requires to add traefik.port and traefik.frontend.rule even if they are not used.
https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/1840

Answer (score 1):

I had also the same problem. I am using docker compose for running the containers and  there are two open ports inside my service and I want to access to every ports with the different domain. I solve it like below

```
    labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.s1.rule=Host(`sub1.sample.com`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.s1.entrypoints=websecure"
  - "traefik.http.routers.s1.service=s1"
  - "traefik.http.routers.s1.tls.certresolver=myhttps"
  - "traefik.http.services.s1.loadbalancer.server.port=8543"
  - "traefik.http.services.s1.loadbalancer.server.scheme=https"

  - "traefik.http.routers.s1.rule=Host(`sub2.sample.com`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.s2.entrypoints=websecure"
  - "traefik.http.routers.s2.service=s2"
  - "traefik.http.routers.s2.tls.certresolver=myhttps"
  - "traefik.http.services.s2.loadbalancer.server.port=9543"
  - "traefik.http.services.s2.loadbalancer.server.scheme=https"
  - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_default"
```

I have also using letsencrypt for handling https

moreover  I add this line for making secure connection between traefik and my container

```
      - "traefik.http.services.s2.loadbalancer.server.scheme=https"
```

if you do not need https you can omit this lines

```
      - "traefik.http.routers.s1.tls.certresolver=myhttps"
```

and change the websecure to web in this line

```
      - "traefik.http.routers.s1.entrypoints=web"
```